# How to convert all csv in a folder from comma delimited to pipe delimited using cmd in windows?

Tags: windows, file, loops, cmd, delimiter

I have a list of CSV files which have comma(`,`) as the delimiter. I want to change the delimiter in all the CSV files in that folder into pipe (`|`). I am very new to coding in windows cmd. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that dbenham has written a batch script called JREPL.BAT to replace text within another file. You can read more about it on Dostips: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044